How to get SQL query from NLP using Openai?
I am working on a POC for NLP to SQL query using the Langchain framework and OpenAI. Sometimes, the generated query has errors and giving wrong query. How can I improve the query generation process?
Should I consider fine-tuning or any other method? Please provide some suggestions to improve the NLP to SQL conversion.

Though I don't have much information (like kind of database & library used, how self descriptive the table and column names are and finally how closely the user query is related to the column names), still will share my experience for the same use case.
I tried to build an agent which can query a Sqlite database for the provided query, the below code worked well when I integrated with GPT-4 model.
from langchain_community.agent_toolkits import SQLDatabaseToolkit
from langchain_community.utilities import SQLDatabase
    
DB= SQLDatabase.from_uri("sqlite:///SqliteDatabase.db")
toolkit = SQLDatabaseToolkit(db=DB, llm=ChatOpenAI(temperature=0))
context = toolkit.get_context()
tools = toolkit.get_tools()
    
messages = [
    SystemMessage("You are a SQL Agent who will try to fetch the data for the provided query."),
    HumanMessagePromptTemplate.from_template("{messages}"),
    AIMessage(content=SQL_FUNCTIONS_SUFFIX),
    MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="agent_scratchpad"),
    ]
    
prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(messages)
prompt = prompt.partial(**context)
llm = ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-4o", temperature=0)
tool = create_tool_calling_agent(llm, tools, prompt)
    
agent = AgentExecutor(
        agent=tool,
        tools=toolkit.get_tools(),
        verbose=True,
    )

Add on info: The agent struggled to form the proper sql query when open source models were provided like Llama3.

Thank you for your information. Does the agent have any token limits?

To my knowledge, no...
